# Why does $\hat{i} \times \hat{j}$ give $\hat{k}$

Tags: vectors, orthogonality

I know that it's by definition, but I'm not entirely satisfied with that answer, can anybody please explain it to me?

Comment: Do you know the geometric meaning of the cross product? I.e. you take two vectors, cross them, and get a third vector that is simultaneously orthogonal to the first two?

Comment: It would also work for it to equal $- \hat k$.

Comment: To understand your question: are you not satisfied with $i\times j$ being equal to $k$ based on defition? or are not not satisfied with the definition behind this answer?

Comment: It would help if you can give your definition of the cross product. If it's the one given by explicitly calculating a $3 \times 3$ determinant, then you can plug in $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ to see that the output is exactly $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: "*$\hat{i} \times \hat{j}$ give $\hat{k}$ ... but I'm not entirely satisfied with that answer*" $\;-\;$ As opposed to *what* other answer? That it could maybe equal $-\hat{k}$, or $+10 \hat{k}$, or something not related to $\hat{k}$ altogether, or perhaps you believe no answer can possibly exist?

Comment: @dxiv Assuming that the OP understands the role of definitions in mathematics and is being rational, my answer below suggests that it is fine to instead *arrive* at that equality, or even to start by defining a different equality.

Comment: @ryang Yours is a good guess as to what the question might have meant to ask. But the OP gave no clue of context, background, level etc, so we can only speculate.

Comment: *below assures that it is fine to

Comment: Im so sorry i wasnt able to respond but what im saying is that I know that cross products give perpendicular resultant vectors but my question is why is it perpendicular and not anything else?

Comment: @Sciencenium But that's a different question, whose answer is this: the cross product of two vectors is *defined* to return some vector that is perpendicular to the input vectors. (Notice also that, unlike dot products, cross products don't make sense in 4D.)

Comment: still the answer as to why icap x jcap gives kcap is because of the perpendicular vector in z-direction so yeah its by definition.

Comment: so should i just visualize that cross product gives perpendicular vectors (btw @ryang thank you so much, appreciated!!)

Comment: @Sciencenium To your previous comment: yes, of course; if you click on my link below, #1 and #2 are *universal* conventions; #3, on the other hand, together with right-handed Cartesian axes, is widely adopted in mathematics & physics, but occasionally, $\hat{i} \times \hat{j}=-\hat{k}$ is encountered together with left-handed Cartesian axes! Confusion arises when we use $\hat{i} \times \hat{j}=\hat{k}$ and draw the $x$ and $y$ axes in the usual directions but with the $z$-axis going into the page rather than out of the page.

Comment: and also that we can find out k or -k from the right-hand rule, so the choice of taking x and y (perpendicular to each other) is ours and then z is determined by them.(thank u @ryang very cool!)

Comment: @Sciencenium Not really: the right-hand rule only gives you the physical direction of the resultant vector, but whether it is denoted by "$k$" or "$-k$" depends on how you have set up your axes (left- or-right- handedly). This is what I mean above (#3) by the two competing conventions.

Comment: sorry, I also meant to say the same, just the wording got a bit messed up, anyways my doubts have vanished!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically saying that you do not accept the definition $$\hat{i} \times \hat{j}:=\hat{k},$$ or at least do not wish to use it.

Then, [alternatively](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4454951/21813),  define your Cartesian coordinate system to be right-handed *so that* $$\hat{i} \times \hat{j}=\hat{k}.$$

On the other hand, a left-handed Cartesian coordinate system corresponds to $$\hat{i} \times \hat{j}=-\hat{k}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The way to think about this **Intuitively** is like this:
We are given two vectors, which will always be in a Plane in a 3D Space/Environment.
[[ In Particular : It may be in the XY Plane. ]]
Is there some way (some operation) to get a vector "Perpendicular" to these vectors ?
[[ In Particular : Is there some way to get a vector in the other Dimension ? ]]

The Answer is via a new operation (**Cross Product**) which will be Defined appropriately.

Likewise, given two vectors, can we get a scalar ?
The Answer is via a new operation (**Dot Product**) which will be Defined appropriately.

These Definitions were chosen/selected over the ages, to be useful Mathematically and Physically.

These Definitions must be logically valid, handling the cases where the two vectors are :
(1) **Perpendicular**, in which case you have the relationship given in your Question &
(2) **Co-linear**, in which case there is no unique Perpendicular vector : the Cross Product must be the "ZERO" vector.